# emulate binary code for QEMU

Tags: compilation, qemu

i'would to cross compile helloworld.c for arm target and run on qemu but i have always the same error when i run this command:

> qemu-system-arm -M vexpess-a9 -kernel test
>
> qemu-system-arm: -kernel test: unsupported machine type

thanks for your help and advices

Comment: you didnt compile your binary for arm, and beyond that if test is the helloworld program which I assume is some printf thing to run on top of some operating system (linux) then that is not how you run it.  if it is bare metal then sure.

Comment: in fact i try to cross compile this helloworld.c (it main function like you say is to print hello world) with this command "arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static helloworld.c -o test"  and i would to test this program on qemu without operating system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in fact i needed to  link software for the adress 0x0010000  to be executed a guest code on host machine because The QEMU emulator is written especially to emulate Linux guest systems; for this reason its startup procedure is implemented specifically: the -kernel option loads a binary file (usually a Linux kernel) inside the system memory starting at address 0x00010000. The emulator starts the execution at address 0x00000000, so we need to place our binary in the correct adress

i follow this [tutorial](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/) and it works for me